# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mini_flask_app' in python 3.x

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

```
import csv
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from mini_flask_app import CSV_FILEPATH

main_bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)


@main_bp.route('/',methos =['GET'])
def index():
    
    with open(CSV_FILEPATH) as csv_file:
      reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
      user_list = [row for row in reader]
    print(user_list)  
    return render_template('index.html', user_list=user_list)
```

[image]

This is my error

```
user@LAPTOP-AT53NEI5 MINGW64 ~/ds-sa-mini-flask (main)
$ C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/user/ds-sa-mini-flask/mini_flask_app/views/main_views.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\ds-sa-mini-flask\mini_flask_app\views\main_views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mini_flask_app import CSV_FILEPATH
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mini_flask_app'
(base)
```

So I wonder how to solve this module error
Help me please...

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add this in the launch.json file?

```
"env": {"PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceFolder}"},
```